# VB6 Download Web Page Source

Tags: vb6, webclient

Is there a way in VB6 to download a web pages source to a string or Textbox? For example in VB.Net the WebClient class allows you to do so using .DownloadString("google.com"), how can I do the same in vb6?

Note: I would like to avoid using a WebBrowser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much about VB6, but in VBA...

```
Dim objHttp As Object, strURL as string, strText as string

Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

strURL = "http://www.yoursite.com/"

objHttp.Open "GET", strURL, False
objHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", _
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHttp.Send ("")

strText = objHttp.responseText

Set objHttp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

You have taken me back years. There is a useful Windows API call for this purpose:

```
Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a little-known way to do this with native VB6, using the [AsyncRead](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277589.aspx) method of UserControl and UserDocument objects - no need for API calls. You can even do it asynchronously if you wish.

Here's an excellent [explanation and VB6 code for multiple simultaneous downloads](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/columns/article.aspx?editorialsid=2560), from the renowned VB6 guru [Karl Peterson](http://vb.mvps.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the URLDownloadToFile function and then read the downloaded file into a string or textbox.

Example Code:  http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/internet/urldownloadtofilenocache.htm