# how to use get data option in excel for multiple urls?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of website URLs in one column lets say A1 to A704

In this format:

```
www.website.com/page=1
www.website.com/page=2
www.website.com/page=3
www.website.com/page=4
```

etc.....to page 704

I want the excel web query command to extract and import the text from each page and then paste it in ONE new sheet in one column, with each page after one another so....

```
Page 1 Text extract

Page 2 Text extract

Page 3 Text extract
```

etc

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build a macro to do so. How familiar are you with VBA?

Check out the answer to this question:
[VB6 Download Web Page Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270563/vb6-download-web-page-source/3272065#3272065)

Comment: thanks for reply im a beginner to vb6 can u please guide me with using VBA in excel?

Comment: Oh. Um, that's going to take more time than I have to help you through that. I suggest you use the Googlemachine to find a worthy guide online or purchase a book. The VBA for Dummies book is pretty good, I'm told.

Comment: The best way to get started is to record a macro while you manually perform part of the task. For instance, I would start recording, then use Excel's "Import Data from Web" tool. After you have done this, stop recording, then view the recorded VBA code. From there, you can figure out how to incorporate that into a loop.